# vpasolve and for loop Matlab

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, numerical-calculus

I am trying to solve numerically symbolic equation. But one variable in my equation is series of values `zv=1:-0.1:0`. So, according to my code:

```
zv=1:-0.1:0
n=length(zv);
j=1:n;
C=15;
eqn=C-64.*(1-zv(j))==0;
R=vpasolve(eqn,x(j),1)
```

I got mistake in the last row that `Index exceeds matrix dimensions`.

Other solution which is working is with for loop, but I dont know how to put all solutions (R) in one variable. I got list in my working space where values are changing and it stops when I use all `zv` terms:

```
syms x;
for zv=1:-0.1:0
C=15;
eqn=C-64.*(1-zv(j))==0;
R=vpasolve(eqn,x,1)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first solution, the 'IndexExceedsMatrixDimension' error is raised by `x(j)` since `x` has not been defined. Your current code will also raise a 'ValueError' since you are not passing a numerical function but just a value to the `vpasolve` function. The following code works by altering the equation like so:

```
zv = 1:-0.1:0.1;
n  = length(zv);
R  = zeros(1,n);
for j=1:n;
    C=15;
    r=vpasolve(C-64.*(1-zv(j)*x)==0, x, 1);
    R(j)=double(r);
    end
R
```

Note that the code above is storing the solutions (R) in an array `R` initialized with `R=zeros(1,n)`. Going with your second solution, you can similarly store the solutions, but you first need to convert the syms to a type that can be stored in an array, e.g., a double. In the code above, you must define `zv = 1:-0.1:0.1` to avoid a 'ValueError' in `vpasolve`, but in the code below you can use `zv = 1:-0.1:0`. I suggest using `warning('off','all')` to avoid the potential type conversion warnings.

```
warning('off','all');
syms x;
zv=1:-0.1:0;
R = zeros(1,length(zv));
for j=1:length(zv),
    C=15;
    R(j)=double(vpasolve(C-64.*(1-x)==0,x,1));
    end
R
```